# Проставить кросс продажи MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно проставить в отдельном столбце доп. продажа, если [Покупатель] покупает в этом [Магазин] не первый раз, соответственно есть и другие записи с его именем&магазином, но разница в [Дата] покупок должна быть не больше 1 года, и [Продукт]<>'сверхсекретный истребитель'. В одну [Дату] может быть две покупки, тогда 'Доп. продажа' надо ставить тому где ID больше. MS SQL.

**Обновление**
Появилась мысль через left join подтянуть точно такую же таблицу, задав условия, но не пойму - он же подтянет мне только 1 строку, отвечающую условию, а если их несколько? Нужно чтобы доп. продажа стояла только у последующих продаж.

```
    select *
from d
Left JOIN d2 ON (d.Магазин=d2.Магазин 
 and d.Покупатель=d2.Покупатель
 and d.Договор<>d2.Договор                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 and DATEDIFF(DD, d.[Дата подписания], d2.[Дата подписания])>=0
 and DATEDIFF(DD, d.[Дата подписания], d2.[Дата подписания])<=300
 and d2.Продукт not in ('Сверхсекретный истребитель','Рулон бумаги'))
```

Comment: Прикрепите схемы таблиц, скорее всего задача решается давольно легко, особенно при наличии таблицы Заказы/Покупки

Comment: @NickProskuryakov Все данные в одной таблице уже. Есть магазин, договор, покупатель, дата подписания, дата оплаты, продукт, продавец и ещё несколько полей

Comment: Какая у вас версия сиквела?

Comment: @NickProskuryakov SQL 2016 v.13

Comment: А 'Доп. продажа' и у первого договора этого покупателя должна появиться?

Comment: @NickProskuryakov Нет, должна появиться только у последующих продаж и то при определённых условиях

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать **CROSS/OUTER APPLY**

```
DECLARE @D AS TABLE
(
    id  int not null identity (1,1),
    store int not null,
    customer int not null,
    contract varchar(50) not null,
    date_sign smalldatetime not null,
    product varchar(100) not null
)

insert into @D
values(1,1,'1','2018-12-01','Жвачка'),
      (1,1,'2','2018-12-05','Картон'),
      (1,1,'3','2018-12-05','SQL Server'),
      (1,1,'4','2016-12-05','Сверхсекретный истребитель'),
      (2,1,'5','2018-12-05','Яблоки'),
      (3,1,'6','2016-12-05','Coca-Cola'),
      (1,2,'1','2018-12-01','Синхрофазотрон'),
      (1,3,'2','2018-12-05','Гравицапа'),
      (1,4,'3','2018-12-05','Iphone 100X'),
      (1,4,'4','2016-12-06','Рулон бумаги')


SELECT d.id,d.store,d.customer,d.contract,d.date_sign , sale.id
FROM @D d
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 id
    FROM @D d2
    WHERE d.store=d2.store 
        and d.customer=d2.customer
        and d.contract<>d2.contract                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        and DATEDIFF(DD, d2.date_sign, d.date_sign)>=0
        and DATEDIFF(DD, d2.date_sign, d.date_sign)<=300
        and d2.product not in ('Сверхсекретный истребитель','Рулон бумаги')
        and d2.id < d.id
    ORDER BY id DESC
) sale
```

**sale_id** - как раз то самое поле, которые вам нужно, как я понял из условий задачи.

Comment: Спасибо большое!